# What is {{#}} in PHP?

Tags: php, mustache

I see alot of `{{#variable}}` and `{{/variable}}` used in PHP code. Most specifically in MVC and Mustache templated apps. I've also seen `{{^variable}}` and `{{/variable}}` used. What are they, and more importantly what are they used for?

Comment: You answered yourself when mentioning *Mustache*! http://mustache.github.com/mustache.5.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is Mustache templating. You can read the [docs for it here](http://mustache.github.com/mustache.5.html).

## `{{#variable}}` and `{{/variable}}`: Section

> Sections render blocks of text one or more times, depending on the
>   value of the key in the current context.
>
> A section begins with a pound and ends with a slash. That is,
>   `{{#person}}` begins a "person" section while `{{/person}}` ends it.
>
> ### False Values or Empty Lists
>
> If the person key exists and has a value of false or an empty list,
>   the HTML between the pound and slash will not be displayed.
>
> Template:
>
> ```
> Shown. 
> {{#nothin}}   
>   Never shown! 
> {{/nothin}}
> ```
>
> Hash:
>
> ```
> {   
>     "person": true, 
> }
> ```
>
> Output:
>
> Shown.

## `{{^variable}}` and `{{/variable}}`: Inverted Section

> An inverted section begins with a caret (hat) and ends with a slash.
>   That is `{{^person}}` begins a "person" inverted section while
>   `{{/person}}` ends it.
>
> While sections can be used to render text one or more times based on
>   the value of the key, inverted sections may render text once based on
>   the inverse value of the key. That is, they will be rendered if the
>   key doesn't exist, is false, or is an empty list.